# 2 quick questions about composed archives

Tags: stream, archive, opentok, tokbox

Is it possible on a composed archive, to show, not only the stream but also the stream name above or below the stream?

I have read that the maximum streams in a composed archive are 9, and the 10th will be ignored. But will it record for example 20 individual streams for the same session?

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my answer for individual stream archive, please see the update below.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

At this time, OpenTok Archiving does not support recording the name of the stream.

Updated (11/27/18):
You can record up to 50 streams when in individual archiving mode.